# A factorial related statement

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Is the following promise problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ or $\mathsf{coNP}$ or even in $\mathsf{PH}$?
$$\Pi:\mathsf{Given}\mbox{ }p,a,s\in\Bbb N,\mbox{ }\mathsf{with}\mbox{ }p\mbox{ }\mathsf{a}\mbox{ }\mathsf{prime}\mbox{ }\mathsf{such}\mbox{ }\mathsf{that}\mbox{ }s<p,\mbox{ }a<p,\mbox{ }\mathsf{is }\mbox{ }0< a!\bmod p < s?$$

$$\mathsf{Conjecture}:\Pi\in\mathsf{PSPACE}\backslash\mathsf{PH}$$

Comment: NP with respect to what? $a$? Or the total number of bits of the data?

Comment: I guess it is the total number of bits (which is basically $\log n$ unless $a$ is very large, which would only help us). The problem is that the obvious algorithm takes about $a$ steps (each of which involves arithmetic in Z/nZ).

Comment: @BorisBukh Yes you are right. Total bits is correct measure. If $a>n$, $a!\bmod n=0$. If $n<s$, then $a!\bmod n<s$ always holds as well. So relevant range is $0<a,s<n$.

Comment: @Arul Word of advice: include some motivation/discussions in your questions. Your questions are good, but they take much thinking to appreciate, which is why they do not get nearly as much attention as they deserve.

Comment: The problem is in [CH](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) by scaling up the uniform TC^0 algorithms for iterated multiplication and integral division due to Hesse, Allender, and Barrington. I don’t see how to make it into PH.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek which results of Hesse, Allender, and Barrington are you quoting?

Comment: The result that integer division and iterated multiplication are in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I mean the research paper? Also how do you scale up uniform $\mathsf{TC}^0$?